# Advanced MySQL Group Query

Tags: mysql, grouping

scenario: I have difficulty in building a single query that would display a report given the schema. Supposedly, the report to be displayed should follow a computation based on the multiplier. For instance: 
  user, number of messages x multiplier

what is needed: mysql query that would display the expected query result.

```
* schema *
table: users
id | name
 1 |  cris
 2 |  dave
 3 |  jona

table: services
id | name
 1 |  standard
 2 |  premium

table: service_users
user_id | service_id | multiplier
 1      |  1         |  1
 1      |  2         |  2
 2      |  1         |  1
 2      |  2         |  2
 3      |  1         |  1
 3      |  2         |  2

table: messages
user_id | service_id | content
 1      |  1         |  howdy
 1      |  1         |  hey
 1      |  1         |  hello
 1      |  2         |  the quantity
 1      |  2         |  insignificant
 2      |  1         |  pill
 2      |  1         |  dock
 2      |  2         |  misty docks
 3      |  1         |  drive
 3      |  2         |  with style
 3      |  2         |  like a hawk
 3      |  2         |  earthling rise
```

query result should look like this

```
 user_id | multiplier(1) | multiplier(2) | total
  1     |  3            |  4            |  7
  2     |  2            |  2            |  4
  3     |  1            |  6            |  7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT users.id,
       COUNT( IF( service_users.multiplier = 1, 1, NULL ) AS m1,
       COUNT( IF( service_users.multiplier = 2, 1, NULL ) AS m2
       FROM users, messages, service_users
       WHERE users.id = messages.user_id AND
             messages.user_id = service_users.user_id
             messages.service_id = service_users.service_id
       GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: awesome! this is the solution I've been looking for.

Comment: by the way, when I append the total "m1 + m2" to the query, there's an sql error that says "Unknown column 'm1' in 'field list'".

Comment: @darkcolonist Yes, that would not work I removed it from my code, I personally prefer doing the `m1 + m2` in my application, you can still do it in MySql with two variables `@m1 := COUNT(...`, `@m2 := COUNT(...` and then `@m1 + @m2`.